# How to make this sentence shorter?

Tags: grammar, phrases, writing, mathematics

It appears that this site does not support LaTeX, so sorry for the ugly formatting. I would like to explain the sentence

> Let X ~ N(mu_x, sigma_x^2) and Y ~ N(mu_y, sigma_y^2).

with plain english. A long version would be

> In other words, X is a normally distributed random variable with mean mu_x and standard deviation sigma_x, and Y is a normally distributed random variable with mean mu_y and standard deviation sigma_y.

However, it is kind of repetitive and long. How could I rephrase so that it is shorter, and still easy to understand?

Answer (score 5):

You could define them both simultaneously in the sentence as opposed to doing one at a time:

> Let X and Y be normally distributed random variables with means mu_x and mu_y and standard deviations sigma_x and sigma_y respectively.